# Rails - Issue with multiple remote database in production/staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I’m currently running a Rails app which uses 2 databases: its own and one from another (not running anymore) app on a different server. The thing is: locally everything goes just smooth, but on our staging server after a few requests the page load hangs forever and then returns `PG::ConnectionBad error:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "***" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port ***`, which is the second database (running on a different server). I use the second (remote) database for `devise` authentication. I think it is something related to the connection pool related to the remote database not properly releasing after use, but I really have no clue at the moment.

```
Rails version: 5.0.0
Postgres version: 9.3
Passenger version: 5.0.29
```

This is the error thrown:

```
PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "********.cloudapp.net" (********) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port ****?
```

As I said that happens after a while, so I really think it has to be something related to `ActiveRecord` connection pool or the connection with the remote database, which is by the way logging this:

```
2016-07-19 16:49:40 UTC LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2016-07-19 16:49:40 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2016-07-19 16:50:05 UTC LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2016-07-19 16:50:05 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

More of it, this is the status of the remote Postgres, retrieved by running `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`:

```
 datid |       datname       | pid  | usesysid |   usename   |                        application_name                         |   client_addr   | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state  |                                           query
-------+---------------------+------+----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 16733 | ******************* | 7620 |    16584 | *********** | Passenger RubyApp: /var/www/**********/current/public (staging) | *************** |                 |        1336 | 2016-07-19 16:51:07.955763+00 |                               | 2016-07-19 16:51:08.015955+00 | 2016-07-19 16:51:08.016093+00 | f       | idle   | SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2
 12035 | postgres            | 7673 |       10 | postgres    | psql                                                            |                 |                 |          -1 | 2016-07-19 16:52:08.773491+00 | 2016-07-19 16:52:11.052339+00 | 2016-07-19 16:52:11.052339+00 | 2016-07-19 16:52:11.052343+00 | f       | active | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
(2 rows)
```

As you can see, the first query, coming from my Rails app, remains in `idle` state, and even if it is one more clue pointing in the connection pool direction I really have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestion would be REALLY appreciated! Restarting Postgres server on the remote server make things work again, so I'm really pointing at Postgres or Rails not releasing connections.

This is the model (`User`) whose connections are creating trouble:

```
class RemoteBaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :other_db_env
end

class User < RemoteBaseModel
  # model logic
end
```

And this is `database.yml`:

```
##### database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 25

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development

staging:
  <<: *default
  database: db_staging
  username: ********
  password: ********

other_db_default: &other_db_default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 25

fanta_users_development:
  <<: *other_db_default
  database: other_db_development

other_db_staging:
  <<: *other_db_default
  host: ********
  port: 1972
  database: other_db_staging
  username: ********
  password: ********
  protocol: md5
```